# Check if array has 1 more element

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am writing a recursive functions. The end of recursion is signaled by array not having any more element in it.

Is there some function that checks if current element of an array is the element in it? sth like `array.isLast()`

Comment: `array.length`? PS: arrays have no any notion of the "current element".

Comment: yeah I guess i will pop out elements with each call and check for the lenght every time

Comment: *I am writing a recursive functions*, we don't see anyone here? Could you at least share the code?

Comment: "Is there some function"....you could always read the documentation yourself and check for it, instead of asking others to do your research for you. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Answer (score 0):

```
if(array.length == 1) {
  let thenthisisthelastelement = array[0]
}
```